# Create multiple pages in an HTML file with navigation links

Tags: html, sql, sql-server, asp-classic

I have a table in a SQL server database, that holds about 20 000 records. I want to display all the records in an HTML or ASP page. But it must be displayed in such a way that the user can only see the first 100 records and with a navigation link or button he can go to another page where, he can see the next 100 records.

For instance the user should have the following options available for navigation:
`First page`, `Previous page`, `Next page`, `Last page`

With the `First page` - the user can navigate and view the first 100 records.

`Previous page` - view the previous 100 records

`Next page`  - view next 100 records

`Last page`  - view last 100 records

I am not a 100% sure how to go about this. I thought of embedding other HTML pages within another that hold each set of 100 records, but sounds oddly wrong. I also thought about a sql query that for the first page it chooses the top 100 records and when a user press `Next page`, the query adjust and checks the current records/position and choose the next 100 records, which sounds like a viable option. But can someone give a few tips or examples, just so i can get some kind of reference that can help me on where to start.

Comment: possible duplicate of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451080/how-to-do-effective-paging-in-classic-asp

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you on?  2012 has an "OFFSET-FETCH" filter which would be good for this scenario.

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2008

Comment: as you are using classic asp you are using adodb for querying the db right? have a look here: http://www.w3schools.com/ado/prop_rs_pagesize.asp and here: http://www.w3schools.com/ado/prop_rs_absolute.asp

Comment: Some good examples here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/202125 and http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/619/ADO-Recordset-Paging-in-ASP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the property of a `Recordset` like below:

```
Set objRS   = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")

objRS.PageSize = 10
objRS.CacheSize = 10
objRS.AbsolutePage = 1
objRS.PageCount
```

Those are some you can use. You can maybe also learn more about it through this links: [Site 1](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/619/ADO-Recordset-Paging-in-ASP) & [Site 2](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/202125)

Thats what I've used
[image]